# How to have multiple dropdown buttons in a navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a new website and want to have mobile accessable dropdowns. Instead of having hover dropdowns, I'm trying to build clickable dropdowns.

I've tried looking at what other people have done but so far have not found someone solving this problem, though I expect it is fairly easy for most website builders. There's a lot of basic things I don't understand yet about HTML / CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="navbar">

  <a href="#home">Info</a>

  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Our methods
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#link">Answer 1</a>
    <a href="#link">Answer 2</a>
    <a href="#link">Answer 3</a>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Products
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="#link">This is the first option</a>
    <a href="#link">This is the second option</a>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
  var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The goal was to have a navbar that has multiple buttons that on click produce a dropdown. What instead happens is that whichever one I click, I always get the first one to open (the one with "answers" rather than "options" in this example).

How could I get each one to open their own dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is due to having the same "id" attribute in both dropdown divs. Though the browser allows it, in HTML ids should be unique (precisely for this kind of scenarios).

Regardless of the fact that there are other better ways to implement this, one quick fix for your situation is:

- Set `id="myDropdown1"` and `id="myDropdown2"` for the first and second dropdowns respectively, to avoid duplicates.
- Change the onclick attributes to `onclick="myFunction(1)"` and `onclick="myFunction(2)"` in the first and second buttons respectively.
- Change `myFunction` to consider that number, something like

```js
    function myFunction(num) {
      document.getElementById("myDropdown" + num).classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: This advice makes it work exactly as it should. Thank you!
Including for the advice about id's.

Comment: This may be beyond the scope of the question, but is there an easy way to hide the others when a new one is opened?

Comment: @MirjamHeijn Something like this at the beginning of `myFunction` for example?
```document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content').forEach(function(dropdown) {
    dropdown.classList.remove('show');
});
```

Comment: @jaoquin gatica Thanks, unfortunately, the dropdowns never show up at all anymore. I also realize I've kinda broken the last bit of code that closes windows, due to it focusing on a specific one. At least now I know what part to fix and work on. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone encountering the same, the solution to my other question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58582128/how-do-i-hide-the-dropdown-of-a-navbar-when-a-user-clicks-elsewhere

Comment: I did have different div ID's for my various buttons, however I had to name the <button onclick="function()" to different function names for each button. I.e. myFunction1(), myFunction2(), etc...